# Recurrence problems of tiling box

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, recurrence

A. A domino is 2 x 1 rectangle. A tiling of a 2 x n rectangle is a non-overlapping covering by dominoes. Determine the number of was we can do this. Set up a recurrence relation.

B. A tile is a three dimensional box of size 2 x 2 x 1. A tiling of a box of size 2 x 2 x n is a non-overlapping covering of this box by tiles(oriented in any manner). Determine the number of ways we can do this. Set up a recurrence relation.

[image: rectangle and box]

For question A, the recurrence relation I did is: T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) , which is a Fibonacci sequence. But for question B, any ideas for this one?

Answer (score 2):

By the same logic as A, you have 3 options at every location, and they "consume" 1, 2 or 2 "slots". That means the recurrence relation is

> T(n) = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2)